# Was there ever a prophet that was also a military commander

Tags: tanach, army-military-war, navi-prophets

Was there ever a prophet in Tanach that made a known prophecy and was also referred to as a military commander?

Comment: Devorah was a prophetess who lead charges alongside Barak. ([Shoftim 4-5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15812/jewish/Chapter-4.htm))

Comment: Consider [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/82377/edit)ing your question and clarifying what prophets you want to know about. There are many whom we consider to be prophets (for example, Moshe) but who are not in the "Nach" section of the Tanach.

Comment: almost all sefer shoftim is full

Answer (score 6):

1. Joshua was visited by a malach of extremely lofty level (though he might not have technically been a prophet). 
   It's also written a few times that God spoke to Joshua, such as in Joshua 1:1-9, 4:2-3, 4:15-16, 5:2, and more. He was visited by a malach who identified himself as the "general of of God" in 5:13. Rashi (5:15) identified the malach as Michael. Joshua wasn't called a prophet by the Sages in the sense that it wasn't his main vocation, but he was granted prophecy at times.
2. King David was granted prophecy (see last chapter of Shmuel B 23:1-7).
3. Shlomo was also granted prophecy once when he had the dream in which God promised to make him wise, and, as the king, he was the commander in chief, but he did not fight any notable wars.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Seh! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This could be improved with more references, such as to the chapters in whuch Joshua is visited, and in which Shlmo received prophecy.

Comment: "...(though he might not have technically been a prophet)." Could you elaborate on that please? Are you referring to the fact that the example you provided may not have been a prophetic vision, or that Joshua himself may not have (technically) been a _Navi_? Please provide sources, or consider editing your answer to dispel confusion.

Comment: according to rambam David and Shlomo were not prophets but spoke with ruach hakodesh!

Answer (score 2):

King Saul was a military commander, as is known. He was also a prophet, temporarily. See [I Samuel 29:24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=164).

Story synopsis:

Samuel had anointed David as "king". Saul became crazy and was constantly afraid that David would usurp him, so he made numerous attempts to try to kill David. In one incident, David fled to join Samuel at his home. Saul first sent several groups of messengers to retrieve David, and each of these messengers began to prophecy when they approached Samuel. Eventually, Saul, himself went to Samuel, and he also became a prophet.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemora in Megila 14b says that Amasa one of the head Generals of Shauls army Ruach Hakodesh prophecy, and we only know Ester one of the 7 prophetesses had *Nevua* (prophecy) from a *Gezeira Shava* (common word that links both passages) from Amasa's Procphecy (Divrei Hayamim 1 12,19):

> ותלבש אסתר מלכות בגדי מלכות מיבעי ליה אלא שלבשתה רוח הקדש כתיב הכא ותלבש וכתיב התם (דברי הימים א יב, יט) ורוח לבשה את עמשי

Sifsei Chachamim also quotes Bereishis 45,27 ותחי רוח יעקב with Yaakov that his Nevua came beck from the passuk regarding Amasa

> רוצה לומר ד**רוח היינו נבואה כדכתיב (דה"א יב יט) ורוח לבשה את עמשי:**

Answer (score 1):

pinchas ben elazar who according to rashi on megilla 14a was a navi, went out to battle the midyanim (bamidbar 31:6) and it sounds as if he was leading the battle, although the ramban and one pshat in rashi learn that he was the *cohen hamashuach*